# How Do I Sum the Total Of The Column Values If filtering the pending values in Angularjs?

Tags: html, angularjs, meanjs

I am using MEAN stack in my application with AngularJS as my front-end. How to `total sum` column values, if some value is filtered in the table, actually I got the `total sum value` but if I do filter like `| filter:{status: 'pending'}` in the table total sum gets overall data values...[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ypRrxvusmNITwhk6fFGz?p=preview)   **For Example** :- in table without `filter` the `amt` values total sum answer I got 5775.30, then in table if I have used filter like `| filter:{status: 'pending'}` `amt`  values  total sum is showing like overall value `5775.30`, Expecting answer like `3850.2`  , If any one knows the solution help to us thanks....

- In table column without filter we got an exact answer and total sum also.
- But in table, if used filter `| filter:{status: 'pending'}` again showing overall data values ... so what we expecting if we used filter  the total sum should be calculate rest of the values ...expecting `amt` answer like 3850.2...please look at [my plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ypRrxvusmNITwhk6fFGz?p=preview)

**My controller:-**

```
    .filter('sumOfValue', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        debugger;
        if (angular.isUndefined(data) && angular.isUndefined(key))
            return 0;        
        var sum = 0;

        angular.forEach(data,function(v,k){
            var keyval;
      if(isNaN(parseFloat(v[key])))
      keyval=0;
      else
      keyval=parseFloat(v[key]);
      sum = sum + keyval;
        });        
        return sum.toFixed(2);
    }
})
```

**My Html:-**

```
    <td >{{mani.amt}}</td>

      <td >{{mani.amount_payment }}</td>

<td >{{mani.status }}</td>
```

**My filter:-**

```
| filter:{status: 'pending'}
```

**My Data:-**

```
            {
"_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
"remarks": "-",
"status": "pending",
"amt": "1925.10",
"cheque_currency": "Rs",
"cheque_value": "300",
"amount_payment": "100",
"debitnote_no_payment": "3",
"supplier_name": "karikalan",
"status": "pending",
"buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
},

{
"_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
"remarks": "-",
"status": "pending",
"amt": "1925.10",
"cheque_currency": "Rs",
"cheque_value": "300",
"amount_payment": "100",
"debitnote_no_payment": "3",
"supplier_name": "karikalan",
"status": "received",
"buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
},

{
"_id": "5816f4fad0be79f809519f98",
"user": {
"_id": "57400c32bd07906c1308e2cf",
"displayName": "mani selvam"
},
"__v": 0,
"created": "2016-10-31T07:38:34.999Z",
"remarks": "-",
"status": "pending",
"amt": "1925.10",
"cheque_currency": "Rs",
"cheque_value": "300",
"amount_payment": "",
"debitnote_no_payment": "3",
"supplier_name": "karikalan",
"status": "pending",
"buyer_name": "Manidesigns"
},
```

I have created with below given answer updated:- [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Oq8bOzG9Rc0RlGLDPEwI?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you change your tr ng-repeat to below , you have not assigned filtered value to resultValue

```
<tr ng-repeat="mani in resultValue=((sryarndebitnote) | filter:{status: 'pending'}) ">
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the filter to the sum results.

```
           <tr>
             <td>sum</td>
             <td>{{resultValue | filter:{status: 'pending'} | sumOfValue:'amt'}}</td>
             <td>{{resultValue | filter:{status: 'pending'} | sumOfValue:'amount_payment'}}</td>
             <td></td>
           </tr>
```

Comment: thank you so much for your answer it's working perfectly...!!!  so I give you upvote thanks for your help...